# Why mark layout cache as invalidated

Tags: cache

I am working on "Multistore functionality for my custome module". I refered core Cms page module. I found code

below in page resource module(Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Page).

```
protected function _afterSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
{
    $oldStores = $this->lookupStoreIds($object->getId());
    $newStores = (array)$object->getStores();
    if (empty($newStores)) {
        $newStores = (array)$object->getStoreId();
    }
    $table  = $this->getTable('cms/page_store');
    $insert = array_diff($newStores, $oldStores);
    $delete = array_diff($oldStores, $newStores);

    if ($delete) {
        $where = array(
            'page_id = ?'     => (int) $object->getId(),
            'store_id IN (?)' => $delete
        );

        $this->_getWriteAdapter()->delete($table, $where);
    }

    if ($insert) {
        $data = array();

        foreach ($insert as $storeId) {
            $data[] = array(
                'page_id'  => (int) $object->getId(),
                'store_id' => (int) $storeId
            );
        }

        $this->_getWriteAdapter()->insertMultiple($table, $data);
    }

    //Mark layout cache as invalidated
    Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->invalidateType('layout');

    return parent::_afterSave($object);
}
```

what below code is doing?

```
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->invalidateType('layout');
```

Is this necessary ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may suspect the line in question invalidates the layout cache.
This is needed in case you added something to the `Layout Update XML` or `Custom Layout Update XML` fields.
I agree that this could be done in a graceful way, bu checking first if something changed in those fields.
But I guess no one bothered to check.
But for sure this is needed.